# Android Shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having an application with a register procedure. The fields are "badge id(username)" and "key(password)". At the beginning of the process, I will set that two input values from shared preferences. I want those two values for my application. When we attempt to give next two values (or editing this values) show a toast like "Badge already taken. Try 'Enter Here !'"
how can I implement these?

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Badge already taken.Try 'Enter Here !'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: i want prevent shared preference memory by editing.i mean that i am only want the values which are enter in the first register time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences.contains(String key)` to test whether your shared preferences already has stored a user name or password.

I would recommend that instead of complaining to the user about changing name or password, that you simply disable or eliminate any UI elements that would allow the user to make changes.

For example, you could do something like this in `onCreate`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
if (prefs.contains(KEY_USERNAME)) {
    // name (and password, presumably) already stored
    // disable/hide appropriate UI elements
} else {
    // no user name stored
    // enable/show elements that allow user to make changes
}
```

You could even decide to use an entirely different layout in the call to `setContentView` based on the above logic.

Comment: how can i toast a message when user edit the already set username and password?please help me for that...how can i disable/hide appropriate UI elements

Comment: @DipinKG - The code you posted in your question should do that nicely. I recommend, however, designing your UI so that the user doesn't have the chance to do anything that you don't want to happen. If you disable or hide the user name field, for instance (or replace it with a non-editable field), then the user would not be able to edit the name in the first place and you would have no need to pop up a Toast.

Comment: how can i disable/hide appropriate UI elements?

Comment: @DipinKG - `findViewById(R.id.user_name_field).setEnabled(false)`. (The id, of course, should be what you use in your layout, and whether you should pass `false` or `true` depends on which branch of the test succeeds.)